# Ascending chain of ideals

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity such that every ascending chain of ideals terminate. Let $f:R \to R$ be a surjective homomorphism. Prove that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Let $\mathfrak{a}_n = \ker f^n$.

Comment: That was the first closest duplicate I could find, but I'm pretty sure there are one or two closer ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Daniel Fischer's comment, since $f$ is surjective all we need to show is injectivity, and the way to do that is to show that $\ker f=0$. How can we use the ascending chain condition? One way is to consider the kernels of $f^2, f^3, \dots$, which form an ascending chain (why?):
$$
\ker(f) \subseteq \ker(f^2) \subseteq \ker(f^3) \subseteq\cdots
$$
What can we conclude about this chain? And how might we use that conclusion to show that $\ker f=0$?

Incidentally, this proposition has a dual statement which I would encourage you to prove as an exercise.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity such that every *descending* chain of ideals terminates. Let $f : R \to R$ be an *injective* homomorphism. Prove that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Am I correct if I say that these kernels behave much like that of linear transformations ?

Comment: Kernels of ring homomorphisms behave like kernels of linear maps in the sense that a ring homomorphism $f:R\to S$ is injective precisely if $\ker f=0$. (That follows from the corresponding fact for abelian groups.) I may not have addressed your answer at the right level because I was unsure of your background. Does that clear things up?

Comment: Yep it does. And thanks for answering. For the dual part, I was thinking of considering any r in R then I need to create an ideal which has decreasing inclusion and thus will terminate giving an x such that f(x) = r. Am I on the correct path ?

Comment: That should do it. You'll find the injectivity hypothesis very useful. Let me know if you hit a snag.

Comment: I'm not being able to think of that ideal. The only thing that is popping in my head is the map f(x) - r, but its not even a homomorphism.

Comment: Pick $r\in R$. We want to show $r$ is in the image of $f$, right? A natural ideal to pick is $(r)$. By analogy with the solution to the previous problem, see what happens when you iterate $f$ on $(r)$.

Comment: Their images have the descending chain property. So for some n f^n(x) = r so f(y) = r where y is in R. Thus f is surjective. Is this correct ?

Comment: Almost. All we can conclude from the descending chain property is that for some $n$, $f^n((a))=f^{n+1}((a))=\cdots$. But this is enough. Do you see why?

Comment: Due to injective property of f I suppose ?

Comment: We want to show that $a$ has a preimage under $f$, and we know that $f^n(a)=f^{n+1}(r)$ for some $r\in R$ since $f^n$ and $f^{n+1}$ have the same image. *Now* use injectivity.

Comment: Thanks man! Cleared all my doubt. You are great !

Comment: If you're interested, rings that satisfy the ascending chain condition are called *Noetherian*. Noetherian rings are very important in commutative algebra -- they're "finite-dimensional" in a certain sense and have many nice properties. Rings that satisfy the descending chain condition are called *Artinian*. It turns out that every Artinian ring is Noetherian, although this isn't obvious from the definitions.